# Method for getting the real roots of exponential and logarithmic type equations

Tags: functions

Lets real roots of equation be $x_1,x_2..$ of   $\log_{2021} x = 2022-x$ and $2021^y = 2022-y$ be $y_1 ,y_2..$ find $x_1+y_1+x_2+y_2..$.

> My method from graph of all three functions separately we can see log and exponential are stricly increasing and so they can cut $y=2022-x$ in atmost one real point , so lets those points be $x_1$ and $y_1$ now putting in both equations we get $\log_{2021} x_1 + x_1 = 2^{y_{1}} + y_1$ now how to show there is only one unique pair of $(x_1,y_1)$ satisfying above equation.   I could have easily guessed the $x_1 ,y_1$ but would like to know properly how do we get the real roots too so that we can get the sum value .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\log_{2021} x = 2022 - x \implies x = \frac{2021^{2022}}{2021^x} \implies x\cdot e^{x\ln(2021)} = 2021^{2022} \\ \implies x\ln(2021)\cdot e^{x\ln(2021)} = \ln(2021) \cdot 2021^{2022}  \implies x = \frac{W\left(\ln(2021) \cdot 2021^{2022}\right)}{\ln(2021)}$$

Computing for $W_0$ and $W_{-1}$, the only real value we get for $x$ is $2021$.

$$2021^y = 2022 - y \implies \ln(2021) \cdot 2021^{2022}\cdot2021^y = \ln(2021) \cdot 2021^{2022}\cdot(2022 - y) \\ \implies \ln(2021) \cdot 2021^{2022} = \frac{\ln(2021) \cdot 2021^{2022}\cdot(2022 - y)}{2021^{y}} \\ = \ln(2021) \cdot (2022 - y)\cdot e^{\ln(2021) \cdot (2022 - y)}\\ \implies \ln(2021) \cdot (2022 - y) = W\left(\ln(2021) \cdot 2021^{2022}\right) \\\implies y = 2022 - \frac{W\left(\ln(2021) \cdot 2021^{2022}\right)}{\ln(2021)}$$

Computing for $W_0$ and $W_{-1}$, the only real value we get for $y$ is $1$.

Hence, $$(x,y) = (2021, 1) \implies \sum \text{roots} = 2021 + 1 = \boxed{2022}$$

Note: $W_k(x)$ is the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). To compute $W_k(x)$ in [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/), simply use `ProductLog[k, x]`.

Comment: Thosr solutions were eqsy to observe too , is there a way to quickly get those real solutions without using Lambert function ? As it came in some competition

Comment: @ProblemDestroyer The interesting thing is that you don't even need to compute the value for the Lambert W function. If you observe, for $x + y$, the Lambert W part simply cancels out giving $2022$.

Comment: @ProblemDestroyer That being said, I'm sure there must be another way.